# Display multiple time zones in status bar

Tags: 16.04, unity, clock, statusbar

What I'm looking to do is add a second clock (specifically UTC) to the status bar, ideally adjacent to the local time. I do much work across time zones, so naturally having a second clock would be useful.

I've searched quite a bit, but am only able to add time zones on the dropdown (which is *not* what I'm looking for).

Hopefully someone else has done this before and can help out!