# Additional time zones in status bar

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell, statusbar

Is it possible to have one or more extra TZs in the status bar, as I'd asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/945450/display-multiple-time-zones-in-status-bar) (that was for Unity, though, so it's not a dupe).

Comment: @jhpratt That part of the question (extra clock in top bar instead of the calendar tray) is addressed by [one of the answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/307957/480481).

Comment: @pomsky That definitely looks right, but how do I start it?

Comment: I have undeleted my detailed answer, check it. Ping me if you need more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A half-baked solution is to use a GNOME shell extension called [MultiClock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/605/multiclock/). Its limitations are:

- Only one extra clock
- Very limited number of time-zones to choose from (more can be added editing its source, see below)

This extension depends on the `gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0` package, install it first (if not installed already) by running

```
sudo apt install gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0
```

#### How to install the extension

You can install the extension by clicking on the ON/OFF toggle in [this webpage](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/605/multiclock/) (you may have to install the `chrome-gnome-shell` package and a browser add-on/extension suggested by the webpage first).

#### How to add more time-zones for selection

1. Open the `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/MultiClock@mibus.org/extension.js` file with a text-editor, for example run

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/MultiClock@mibus.org/extension.js
   ```
2. In the `Timezones` section (line number 22) add your preferred time-zone following the format of the default ones, e.g.

   ```
   'UTC': { hr: 0, min: 0, tzname: 'UTC' },
   ```

   (Google the correct `tzname` for your preferred time-zone)
3. Save the file.
4. Log out and log in again.

Comment: Apparently I needed to install `chrome-gnome-shell`. After doing that, I toggled a switch and it's in the status bar. Now I can customize the styling so it looks like it fits in.